# How to initialize std::vector without a cycle?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, std, cycle

```
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (size_t i=0; i<100; i++) 
       v.push_back(0);
```

As you see it's the same value repeated for each element. Is there a way to initialize a vector without a cycle? If not, which is the fastest way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the constructor taking a size. This will value-initialize all elements. For `int` this means zero initialization:

```
std::vector<int> v(100); // 100 elements with value 0
```

If you need a different number, then you can pass a second parameter with the desired value:

```
std::vector<int> v(100, 42); // 100 elements with value 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the answer from @juanchopanza if you want to initialize on construction; but if you want to set the same value for all records in the `vector` in any other part of your code you may consider adopting [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

Comment: You don't want to do that.  `v.resize( value )` or `v.insert( v.end(), n, value )` would be much better solutions.

Comment: For the usual reason: always prefer a member function of the container when it exists, if for no other reason than it will be more efficient.  (In this case: `resize` or `insert` will never do more than one reallocation.  `std::fill` could do many.)